# Can anyone identify this vintage 42 pin IC and the company logo?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, vintage

The 42-pin chip is labeled as an LC6064 3090 6m2. I am unable to identify it or the company logo. Anyone recognize this?

[image]

Comment: The logo is from Sanyo.

Comment: if you really want an answer  then provide more than the minimal information you provided ... which device is this component from? ... provide a clear, well lit picture of the area surrounding the IC and a picture of the whole PCB ... it may jog someone's memory

Comment: You might try asking this on the Retro-computing StackExchange website.  There are a lot of people on there who are really good at identifying old chips.

Comment: What was said about Retro Computing, for sure.  At least in the US, a 42-pin chip is definitely an oddball package.  I don't remember ever seeing one back in the day, even in a datasheet.

Comment: There were some parallel ROM/OTPROM/EPROM memory chips in that package. The '64' in the P/N is a bit suggestive. 4M x 16 mask ROM maybe. Just a wild guess.

Comment: Logo is Sanyo, part may be from late 70's (ish).  Here is a fairly similar 42 pin dip available on Ebay: https://www.ebay.com/p/1201611201

Comment: @Nedd 30th week of 1990, maybe? Assuming they were using the Western calendar, and not Shōwa era dates or whatever.

Comment: Assuming approximate manufacturing date 1990, [here](https://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet_pdf/macronix-international/MX23C6410PC-10_to_MX23C6410PC-15.pdf) is a similar era part in the same package from another manufacturer.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the prompt and helpful feedback. On further inspection of the CB from which the chip came, it looks like it is from an old digital clock with a 4x7 segment vacuum fluorescent display similar to this one, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8219/help-wanted-with-vacuum-fluorescent-display-vfd

Comment: All I need is a datasheet and maybe I can put this chip to some use. Thanks.